# I have a type that is union of two interfaces that differ by one property, why can't TS recognize when I omit a common property and add it back?

Tags: typescript

[Here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBSgJWAEygF4oAiHAUQBFSAaLKAeWQEMQBzYYsxnAQQByAcQqkMAXwwZQkKAAUWAYwDWLTugYBlAJYcEXEqU0BJYQBlR9bAFkwCAC7aADvu6lrAVTMAVY3ItiksAAHk4o9lC69sDIAGZKXJoAFs4QoPY6elyY2Nr4AFxQAM72yLrsANwMiogohfBIyFZQTkqqnIUKKmrAAHSZ7PoSUiFhyBFRMfGKiSlOaSD2tg7OrjmRBcWl5VXYNY31tU0Mrd0d8m09vcuOLsDNAI5gbI72AJ6F4BAARjHDGO8nLNUuluMkQYsBq4AD5QcHzdI3VbAKQ1EAlYqFeELCIkdZ5QoAcgAjITaFBqkdDo1enh8M1Tu1gJ1Lpx+uVXP8MGiMSx8PhjPhvHBmPgYtwABRFOY4wqMCDaewAHmx6XJhLyhIAfABKLEy0FELVQCXrXrm6UQ+zNAlQQkAJkJEh1UldGCAA) is the Typescript playground with the code for this question, which is below as well.

Essentially

```
enum Color {
  Red = "RED",
  Orange = "ORANGE"
}

enum Package {
  Single = "SINGLE",
  Multiple = "MULTIPLE"
}
export interface ShipmentSingle {
  id: string;
  color: Color,
  package: Package.Single
}

export interface ShipmentMultiple {
  id: string;
  color: Color,
  package: Package.Multiple,
  quantity: number
}

type Shipment = ShipmentSingle | ShipmentMultiple

const s: Shipment = {
  id: '1', 
  color: Color.Red,
  package: Package.Single 
}


const addIdToOrder = (shipment: Omit<Shipment, 'id'>): Shipment => ({
  ...shipment,
  id: '2'
})
```

I see the error

> Type '{ id: string; color: Color; package: Package; }' is not assignable to type 'Shipment'.
>     Property 'quantity' is missing in type '{ id: string; color: Color; package: Package; }' but required in type 'ShipmentMultiple'.

**Why is this?**

Answer (score 1):

Error happens because `Omit` internally use `keyof T`. `keyof T` when applied to union type (`Shipment` is union type) returns only keys that exists in both types that union consists of.

```
type Keys = keyof Shipment; // Keys = 'id' | 'color' | 'package'.
```

The reason for this is [described here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12815#issuecomment-266250230).

So `Omit<Shipment, 'id'>` produces object with `color` and `package` properties. `quantity` does not exist.

To solve this issue I may reccomend to use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to first distribute `Shipment` to  `ShipmentSingle` and `ShipmentMultiple` and then apply `Omit` to each of them. So result will be again union type.

```
type OmitWithDistribution<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends any ? Omit<T, K> : never;

const addIdToOrder = (shipment: OmitWithDistribution<Shipment, 'id'>): Shipment => ({
    ...shipment,
    id: '2'
})
```